# How manage a large interface for a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

When thinking of the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), I find that an application that I'm writing is getting out of hand for our main interface/form. I'd like to change it before we get too far into the project.

What are some techniques for making a large interface that has a "drawing surface" with toolbars, menus etc? I'd also like it to be easy for this form to be testable. Should there be other classes that know how to control the `MainForm` such as a `ChangedStateTracker` (to monitor dirty state), `DocumentCreator` or something along those lines to "File > New" a new document?

The problem that I'm running into is there are *so many* methods inside the `MainForm.cs` and it's really starting to get ugly to maintain.

This can be marked CW if necessary. Any other hints/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Split your code. Forms are created as partial classes anyway, so organize methods into more code files, and of course think of what might be logical units of code that can be moved into separate classes. Also, if you're using VS2010, consider using extensions such as VS10x Code Map, which is an immense help in coping with large code files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If this is an option, I would create a set of user controls that together produce the entire form.**

These separate user controls can then have their own responsibility and can be tested separately.

**For the logic itself, create classes.**

You can create classes like `CreateDocumentCommand` that implement some functionality. When e.g. the new document button/menu item is clicked, create an instance of this class and execute it.

```
public interface ICommand
{
    bool CanExecute { get; }
    void Execute();
}

public class SaveDocumentCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute
    {
        get
        {
            return MainForm.Instance.CurrentDocument.IsDirty;
        }
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        // Save your document here.
    }
}
```

This by the way is how WPF does it.

Comment: @Pieter - Yup the "main drawing surface" is already a control on it's own (and it's too large already but that's another story). There's *really* only just the main drawing surface and menus/toolbars. I'm obviously OK with putting event handler hooks inside the `MainForm.cs`, but having the "new document" logic (etc.) just feels *wrong* in there...

Comment: Also - I think the "large interface" in my title is a bit misleading (seeing as how there isn't much to it), sorry about that.

Comment: Expanded the answer. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @Pieter - Thanks for your edit, I'm currently heavily using the command pattern throughout.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky - Could you then be more specific as to what your problem is. Sounds like your setup is roughly OK :).

Comment: @Pieter - Heh, yeah I know I was thinking that too. Perhaps I will just stick to commands and move things out further into commands as much as I can.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky - Sounds like a sound solution to me :).

Answer (score 2):

Jeremy Miller has written about this a few times - these should get you started:

- http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/articles/129546.aspx
- http://www.jeremydmiller.com/ppatterns/default.aspx